# Print object with nested properties as string of comma separated key-value pairs

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, json.net

I have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
}
```

As an end result, I would like to print out a `Person` instance as JSON, but I'd like it to be a huge string of key-value pairs, e.g.:

```
"Name:John,Surname:Doe,Line1:Infinite Loop,Line2:California"
```

Notice that in the example above, I got rid of the actual class names (i.e. it prints out `Line1` instead of `Address.Line1`) - i only care about all the name/value pairs.

So the end result would be an array of `Person`s:

```
"persons":[
    "Name:John,Surname:Doe,Line1:Infinite Loop 1,Line2:California",            
    "Name:Jane,Surname:Doe,Line1:Infinite Loop 2,Line2:California"
]
```

As a starting point, I tried using reflection:

```
void Main()
{
    var persons = new List<Person>();
    persons.Add(new Person
    {
        Name = "John",
        Surname = "Doe",
        Address = new Address
        {
            Line1 = "Infinite Loop",
            Line2 = "California"                
        }
    });

    foreach(var person in persons)
    {
        var properties = new List<string>();
        foreach(var property in person.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            properties.Add($"{property.Name}:{property.GetValue(person, null)}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", properties));
    }
}
```

But I get the following output in LINQPad:

```
Name:John,Surname:Doe,Address:UserQuery+Address
```

I assume `Address` is not properly iterated upon because it's a nested object within `Person`. Even so, this doesn't look like the most clean/efficient approach.

Comment: Now, you could reflect on the properties of the UserQuery.Address object to get their values. That said, why don't you use "proper" JSON serialization, for example with the help of Json.NET? (It seems to me you want to reinvent the wheel...)

Comment: @elgonzo because i only need all properties as name/value separated by `,`. With JSON, `Address` would become an object within `Person` (i.e. wrapped in `{ }`), which is something that I can't do. If there is, coudl you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Create a new class with just the properties you want to serialize (commonly known as a DTO), map your complex objects into a collection of DTOs then let the inbuilt serializer do it's thing.

Comment: @ChrisPickford maybe I'm misunderstanding something, I want to essentially flatten the object so there is no hierarchy/nesting, and print everything as string of key-value pairs. Won't the serializer respect the nesting (which is something I don't want)?

Comment: If normal JSON (de)serialization is not feasible in your scenario, then either reflect on on the UserQuery.Address object (as mentioned in my first comment), or equip UserQuery.Address with a `ToString()` override as shown in the answer below. (But please reconsider and verify your assumptions/thougts/ideas/etc... that led you to the conclusion that JSON serialization of Peson into a JSON object is not feasible for your use case. After all, avoiding JSON serialization and building some custom JSON text representation should have a reason that justifies the effort you have to put into  it...)

Comment: (Keep in mind, at some point you want to read the JSON back into some program/service again. Your JSON "flavor" would require some custom text parsing. Unless this custom "flavor" is a requirement by some already existing program/service, who would implement that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) like so:

```
class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Person);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var pairs = JObject.FromObject(value)
            .Descendants()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Value is JValue)
            .Select(p => p.Name + ":" + p.Value);
        writer.WriteValue(string.Join(",", pairs));
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it by passing the converter to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, new PersonConverter());
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L4YDsm

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ToString` override to your class and return a collection of strings as JSON.

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return $"Name:{Name},Surname:{Surname},Line1:{Address?.Line1},Line2:{Address?.Line2}";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Chris. I'm trying to avoid hardcoding all the properties in, the object is much larger in reality.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the reflection in a way that it could go deeper into the structure of your object in order to do what you want. Here's a simple recursive and generic adaptation to your provided code.

```
public static string GetRecursivePropertyValues(object obj)
{
    var properties = new List<string>();
    foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object currentPropertyValue = property.GetValue(obj);
        if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            properties.Add($"{property.Name}:{currentPropertyValue}");
        else
        {
            var subProperties = GetRecursivePropertyValues(currentPropertyValue);
            properties.Add(subProperties);
        }
    }
    return string.Join(";", properties);
}
```

This implementation first verifies if each property is defined with a primitive type or `string` (which are not considered primitive types in C#) and prints them normally if that's the case. Else, if the type is complex (like if it is declared as an `Address` instance), it recursivelly retrieves the properties of the complex object, and adds them to the resulting string.

You can call it like:

`string propertiesStr = GetRecursivePropertyValues(person);`

Edit: code now only flattens the object as required by OP (previous code sample used some rustic JSON formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Using Newtonsoft.json

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Check the above link... It will tell you how to serialize an object to json, it's important to note, you will want to add all your items to a list, then serialize the list into json to get the desired effect

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };
```

There example:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was asked about how to get the `Person` properties into a string of bare key-value pairs inside the JSON, including the properties of the child object.

Comment: no this isnt a plug and play answer, like i said op will have to do some modding, but the code is there. i suppose i could just do it for him, but i didnt think that was why we come here...